# Mach Zehnder classical output

Tags: optics, interference, interferometry

$E_{0}$ is input to the first beam splitter

and the output from the first beam splitter:

$|E_{0}|^2=|E_{1}|^2+|E_{2}|^2$

$E_{1} = \frac{E_{0}}{\sqrt{2}}\;sin( \omega t - kx)$

$E_{2} = \frac{E_{0}}{\sqrt{2}}\;sin( \omega t - kx + \varphi)$

Both beam splitters are $50:50$

$|R| |T| e^{i(\phi_{R}-\phi_{T})} + |R| |T| e^{-i(\phi_{R}-\phi_{T})} = 0$

$2 cos (\phi_{R}-\phi_{T}) = 0 \implies (\phi_{R}-\phi_{T}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

So the output from second beam splitter is equal:

$E_{3} = i |R| E_{1} + |T| E_{2}$

$E_{4} = |T| E_{1} + i |R| E_{2}$

$\begin{pmatrix} E_{3} \\ E_{4} \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} i & 1 \\ 1 &i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} E_{1} \\ E_{2} \end{pmatrix} $

Then I calculate $|E_{3}|^2$ and $|E_{4}|^2$ and the intensities are the same after but they shouldn't.

What I am missing?

Comment: why shouldn't they be?

Comment: @flippiefanus Because for single photon case they aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you haven't been consistent with the application of the beam splitting operation. The Mach-Zehnder interferometer can be explained fully by the operations

$\left|\text{out}\right>=P_{\pi/2}UP_{\pi/2}\left|\text{in}\right>$

with

$P_{\pi/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}i &1 \\ 1&i\end{pmatrix}, \qquad\text{and}\qquad U=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\phi_A} &0 \\ 0&e^{i\phi_B}\end{pmatrix}$,

where $\phi_{A,B}$ are the phases accumulated during the intermediary paths of the interferometer. If you run this through with $\left|\text{in}\right>=E_1$. You'll get the correct result for the output amplitudes. Or simply replace $E_1\rightarrow iE_1$ in your expressions.

That being said, if I calculate $|E_3|^2$ and $|E_4|^2$ as you have defined them. I do not get the same result

$\begin{align}|E_3|^2=&\frac{1}{2}\left(|E_1|^2+iE_1E_2^*-iE_1^*E_2+|E_2|^2\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\left(|E_1|^2+|E_2|^2-|E_0|^2\sin(\omega t-kx)\sin(\omega t-kx+\varphi)\right),
\end{align}$

and

$\begin{align}|E_4|^2=&\frac{1}{2}\left(|E_1|^2+iE_2E_1^*-iE_2^*E_1+|E_2|^2\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{2}\left(|E_1|^2+|E_2|^2+|E_0|^2\sin(\omega t-kx)\sin(\omega t-kx+\varphi)\right)
\end{align}$

Comment: I've updated the post, it should be more clear. The $E_{0}$ is the input.

Comment: I still don't think you've applied the first beam splitter correctly. You say $E_0$ is the input to the first beam splitter but then you also equate it to the output of the first beam splitter?

Comment: The output intensity from the first beam splitter is equal to its input intensity, due to conservation of energy.

Comment: Yes, input energy is equal to output energy $|E_0|^2=|E_1|^2+|E_2|^2$, $E_0\neq E_1+E_2$. If you have some input beam say $E_0\propto\sin(\omega t-kx)$ and apply the beam splitting operation as you have defined it, you do not get the result you have obtained.

Comment: That being said, even though the beam splitter isn't consistent, the answer should only change by a phase factor. I've updated the answer as I don't get the same results for the final output as you have.

Comment: If I have input beam $E_{0} \propto sin( \omega t - k x)$ and apply beam splitting operation, what should I get?

Comment: For $|E_3|^2\propto\left(1-\cos(\varphi)\right)$. Immediately after is just $E_1\propto i\sin(\omega t-kx)$, and $E_2\propto \sin(\omega t-kx)$, by your definition of the beam splitter.